# Minimizing the code using the enumerate function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, for-loop, enumerate

Down below I have a function that checks and outputs any common number within the `list_1, list_2, list_3` is there a way that I could use the `enumerate` or any other function function that would minimize the middle part of the code.

Bit that need minimization:

```
for elem in l1:#loop to access l1elements
    if elem in l2:#checking for element in l2
        if elem in l3:#checking for element in l3
```

Full Code:

```
def intersect(l1, l2, l3) :#function
    for elem in l1:#loop to access l1elements
        if elem in l2:#checking for element in l2
            if elem in l3:#checking for element in l3
print (element) #display element

list_1 =[27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10]
list_2 = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
list_3 = [19, 21, 11, 24, 16, 17, 18, 22, 26, 10, 23, 29, 27, 13, 25, 14, 15, 20, 28, 12]

intersect(list_1, list_2, list_3) #calling function
```

Comment: does the post(s) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy `intersect1d` method to find the common values in the lists or array

```py
def intersect(l1, l2, l3):
    print(reduce(np.intersect1d, (l1, l2, l3)))
```

Result:

---

```py
[10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
```

Code:

---

```py
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce


def intersect(l1, l2, l3):
    print(reduce(np.intersect1d, (l1, l2, l3)))


list_1 = [27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10]
list_2 = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
list_3 = [19, 21, 11, 24, 16, 17, 18, 22, 26, 10, 23, 29, 27, 13, 25, 14, 15, 20, 28, 12]

intersect(list_1, list_2, list_3) #calling functio
```

Answer (score 0):

@tony selcuk - It seems that you've tried to loop 3 lists to find corresponding matching numbers? In that case, You could try this code snippet to see if it works as you want. It used the enumerate() to loop all 3 lists together and get their (index, num) as tuple to compare if there is a match.  Just run it. Once it proves to work as expected, you can turn it into a function easily. This approach will find all matching numbers that appear in all three list and at the **SAME position (index).**

```py
for i, j, k in zip(enumerate(list_1), enumerate(list_2), enumerate(list_3)):
    #print(i, j, k)
    
    if i == j == k:
        print("number:{} order:{}".format(i[1], j[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`set` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead.

```
set_1 = set([27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10])
set_2 = set([14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15])
set_3 = set([19, 21, 11, 24, 16, 17, 18, 22, 26, 10, 23, 29, 27, 13, 25, 14, 15, 20, 28, 12])

set_1.intersection(set_2, set_3)
```

Comment: The syntax has error.  Please double check & correct.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood. this is class method.